# Remove values deselect chosen select jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I have a chosen select box that listing all the standards of the particular school. When I selecting the particular class, listing the students of that class.

I want to close particular class, remove the students of that class. I have a problem in removing the class.Now all students are appended not remove.

**Code Sample**

```
                    <label>Classes</label>

                      <select multiple="multiple" id="selClasses"  name="classes[]" class="chosen-select form-control" data-placeholder="Select Class">                                 

                        <?php foreach($standard_batch as $row){?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $row->cls_id?>" <?php echo (isset($classes) && ($classes==$row->cls_id)? 'selected="selected"' : set_select('classes[]',$row->cls_id));?>><?php echo $row->std_name;?> <?php echo $row->bat_name;?></option>

                         <?php  }?>
                     </select>



       <div class="row mb-2 hidden" id="hidden-chose-box">
                              <div class="col-sm-12">

                                <select class="chosen form-control" id="view-student-list-chosen" name="students_class[]" multiple="true">
                               </select>
                             </div>
                    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
  $(document).on('change','#selClasses',function(){ 
  var class_id=$(this).val();   
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'controller/getStudentClass',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            csrf_test_name : csrf_token,
            id : $(this).val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
           // $("#list-student-loader").html(''); 
            $("#hidden-chose-box").removeClass('hidden');
            $.each(data,function(index,classes){
                $('#view-student-list-chosen').append('<option value="'+classes.stu_id+'" selected >'+classes.stu_firstname+'</option>').trigger("chosen:updated");
            }); 
           // $("#list-student-loader").html(''); 
        },
    }); 
});
```

Up to this working properly. I need to remove the students when deselect a particular class

Answer (score 0):

Clearing value should remove the data that are already been there, only after that you can append the new data to a drop-down list,

you should clear the dropdown list fisrt with

```
$("#view-student-list-chosen").empty();
```

then you can append new values to the DDL :-

```
    if (data != "") {
        $.each(result, function (i, data) {
 $("#view-student-list-chosen").append($('<option></option>').val(data.stu_id).html(data.stu_firstname))
                            })
                     }
```